# Problem in posting Django API it shows "name": [ "This field is required." ]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

this is my serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Movie

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name=serializers.CharField()
    description= serializers.CharField()
    viewed = serializers.BooleanField()

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

this is my models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    viewed=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

this is views.py

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        movies=Movie.objects.all()
        serializer=MovieSerializer(movies,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer=MovieSerializer(data=request.POST)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

this is what my output looks like

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "description": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: and what data do you post?

Comment: any data like.{
        "name": "abc",
        "description": "xyz",
        "viewed": true
    }

Comment: What is inside `request.POST`? Maybe `request.data` will work

Comment: That error is because you don't send the required fields from `request.POST`. Try to add `null=True, blank=True` in the model or just give them to the create function

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to change the serializer like that

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name=serializers.CharField()
    description= serializers.CharField()
    viewed = serializers.BooleanField()

    def create(self, name, description, viewed):
        return Movie.objects.create(name=name, description=description, viewed=viewed)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your views.py, we can see request.POST, there from request we get data not POST, POST is API Method.

```
serializer=MovieSerializer(data=request.POST)
```

So change that line to this:

```
serializer=MovieSerializer(data=request.data)
```

and below you are returning serializer data not POST.

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```